# Jquery Match URL before a special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to match url till a special character '_' if it is present

`var url = window.location;`

var url should get part of url before '_'
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_10

i.e
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method will do it:

```
window.location.href.split('_')[0]
```

Comment: `split()` returns an array, the `[0]` will specify the *first* element of that returned array; which is the part of the URL that comes before the `_` on which the location was split.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = window.location.href;
// http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_10

var new_url = href.slice(0, href.indexOf('_'));
// http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25
```